# Two column bibliography in 9pt with no Bibliography title, no article titles and use journal abbreviations

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, etoolbox

I'm trying to squeeze a two column bibliography into a one column `article` document using this in the preamble. So far so good:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}%
  {\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\refname}]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endthebibliography}{\endlist}%
  {\endlist\end{multicols}}{}{}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

Can you please help me remove the title from the article, underline a particular author and using the tersest possible journal abbreviations please? Otherwise I think I will have to resort to a `\begin{itemize}` and do it by hand.

Comment: Why do you have these specific requirements? If you are submitting a paper to a conference and you need to fit your document within the page limit, then you should take into account that 1. the conference probably has strict requirements for the formatting of the bibliography that you are not allowed to change (including the number of columns) and 2. they may have a BibTeX style file (`.bst`) available that takes care of the formatting. If you are just writing a document for yourself then you could possibly reconsider the formatting you want to use.

Comment: It's a research proposal. No bibliography style requirements, but must be legible and fit on 2 pages.